# moving of a material point on the surface - paraboloid spiral

Tags: plotting

I have to do project on my studies. I wanna place spiral in this shape. I'm stuck on this point:

[image]

I have these details:

z=4x^2+2y^2
spiral  w= (0,0,0) spiral in up

Do you have any ideas? Every answer will be appreciaeted. I use Wolfram Mathematica 7.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use make a spiral separately and combine with `Show`.

```
Show[Plot3D[4 x^2 + y^2, {x, -70, 70}, {y, -70, 70}, Mesh -> None],
  ParametricPlot3D[{u/2 Cos[u], u Sin[u], u^2}, {u, 0, 40 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image]

```
L = 70;
Export["par.gif", Table[
   Show[Plot3D[ x^2 + y^2, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, Mesh -> None, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
   PlotRange -> {0, 5000}, ClippingStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], 
   ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[u], u Sin[u], u^2}, {u, 0, 25 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
   Graphics3D[{Black, Scale[Sphere[{t Cos[t], t Sin[t], t^2}, 5], {1, 1, L}]}]]
 , {t, 0, 25 Pi, Pi/8}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! I think that this model is enough for me but... not for my professor. I'm still wondering about way to improving this model. I would like to add something what would animate move on that actual spiral. It might be ball or something else. whatever. That would certainly be very beneficial and useful from a professor point of view.

Comment: @corey no to judge, but as professor I would primarily value the students doing their work.